# Why is Twokinds called that? I count at least three sentient species

Tags: webcomics, twokinds

There are at least three distinct sentient species in [Twokinds](http://twokinds.keenspot.com/): humans, keidran, and basitins. If you count the four types of keidran separately (fox, wolf, tiger, dog), that brings the count up to five. If you count the western Basitins separately from the normal Basitins, that brings the count up to six. And there are others which may or may not qualify as species, like dragons.

So why is the comic called "**Two**kinds"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comics' Overview says it is about **two main** races:

> ***Overview***: Twokinds is a webcomic that takes place in a world conflicted with racial tension, **primarily between the human-like Humans and the animal-like Keidran**. They have dramatically different societies and ideas on how to live and act. **It is because of these differences that the two races are almost always in some form of conflict**. The story begins as the world hinges on the brink of another war. However, unlike before, this time war seems to be the result of a single man, manipulating **the two races** for his own personal gain - though he no longer has any memory of doing so.

The "about" page on the comic continues:

> ***Races***: Twokinds have three major races: Humans, Keidran, and Basitins. However, **most of the conflict surrounds the first two**. Humans are your standard primate-based, bipedal, sentient animals. They are technologically superior to the other two races, due to their high intelligence and natural curiosity.

Specifically, Basitins are discounted due to their isolation:

> Basitins are a little-known race of bipedal, long-eared, brown-furred, sentient animals. **Unlike the other two races**, the Basitins live off the mainland on a distant island-continent. Due to their isolation, **they are often forgotten by the other two races and left to their own devices**.

Comment: +1. The fact that DVK might have finally had to look something up has made my day. (Or are you a TK reader as well?)

Comment: @Whaaaaaat - nope, just Google-fu this time, sorry. I have ~50 active webcomics I read and about 100 on backlog - so while TK sounds interesting, at the end of the backlog it went.